# How to view the list of backup files by clicking on the latest file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration

I am trying to create an ftpserver app, I create a file, edit it and when i upload it, a backup file is created, that is the old content with the file name as the originalFileName+Timestamp. And the old content is stored in the backup file. 
eg:latest/original file = test.html
backupfile = test_20180727_201800.html

in the UI i want to just display the latest files, and when clicked on the latest file, i want the list of backup files to be shown too, should this work be done in the frontend part or the backend?
I decided to create a Hashmap like

```
HashMap<FtpFileInfo, List<FtpFileInfo>>
```

where

> K=original/latest file and V= the list of Backup Files

.Is there a better way to do this? and also, is there a way to know which file is the backup, where running the program through a loop, because , a user may create a file like test_2020_1243.html, so is there a better way to compare it than by using the underscores as the way to equate.

Answer (score 0):

From one side I would suggest to take a look into the `MGET` FTP [command](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) to pull files from the FTP by some pattern.

On the other hand I would store locally only file names if there is really a problem with the pattern. Then I would use `GET` command for each name.

Comment: Im not thinking about retrieving the files, its sort of just displaying them, suppose i have a file Artem.html , and the backup is Artem_20180727_201800.html, is there a logic to know that Artem is the original? do i test them by the name of the file? because a person may create Artem_Bilan.html .

Comment: That’s fine, you can use LS command. You can store backup files in the particular directory with the name of original file name.

Comment: please see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591948/how-to-create-a-backup-of-a-file-using-spring